# How to select row values for max(2 columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working out a query in MS SQL Server. I have my table like this

Table( Level int, Stage int, values varchar)

```
Level Stage Value
1     1   
1     2  
1     3 
2     1 
2     2
```

I need to find the row having maximum value by level and then by stage. ie., I need to get the result as

```
Level  Stage 
2      2
```

When I try the below query I get the value 22 and in one column. I need that in 2 distinct columns as specified above.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(wfLevel as varchar(2)) + CAST(approvalStage as varchar(2)))
  FROM [AuditReporterDB].[dbo].[RequestHistory]
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 Level,Stage
FROM tableName
ORDER BY Level Desc,Stage Desc
```

Comment: Pretty simple and this is the answer. I missed it.